# Notifications in Node.js

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to achieve a notification system using NodeJS. Everything is going right: connecting to server, connecting to database, querying the database. Since I have just couple of hours working on NodeJS, I don't have the image clear how the notifications concretely happen. Googeling the issue didn't come actually with great things. 
When someone posts a comment, the comment's inserted to the database, that should fire an event to notify his friends (in Friend table) that he posted a comment? Any type of help will be appreciated.
I'm using PHP and MySQL with "mysql" Node module.

Comment: Have a look at http://socket.io/

Answer (score 1):

Googleing "node.js notifications" I got this http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/?p=272 or this http://gonzalo123.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/real-time-notifications-with-php/. It uses socket.io as Amberlamps suggests.

Comment: I've seen it Karel. He used an XML file, I want to use Node.js directly to notify friends about the comment. So any changes in the Comment table will fire the event. Anyway I'll try to get familiar with Socket.io as you suggested, starting from the documentation is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the end you will want to have all of your users (their webbrowsers) run some javascript that opens a websocket (or otherwise, check out Socket.IO) to your node.js server. That connection stays open as long as they stay on the page. Once you want to send them a notification the node.js server does that through this connection. Your PHP script can trigger the node.js server through various ways, but a http request to localhost is probably the easiest and most realtime.